# Plotting exponential function returns excess lines

Tags: r, plot, line, nls

I am trying to fit a non-linear regression to a set of data. However, when ploted, R returns many different lines where there should only be one.

This problem is only reproducable in one set of data and I can't see any obvious difference between this data and others.

This is the code for my plot:

```
plot(df$logFC, df$log_pval, 
  xlim=c(0,11.1), ylim=c(0,11),
  xlab = "logFC", ylab = "p_val")

c <- df$logFC
d <- df$log_pval

model = nls(d ~ a*exp(b*c), start = list(a = 2,b = 0.1))

lines(c, predict(model), col = "dodgerblue", lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

And here is a sample of my data (df):

```
logFC   log_pval
4.315   2.788
6.724   9.836
2.925   4.136
5.451   10.836
2.345   1.486
4.219   7.618
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the model, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) `ggplot` method

I tried graphing the data using `ggplot2` and I think the output is more what you were expecting...

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Create dataset
df <- tibble::tribble(~logFC, ~log_pval,
                      4.315,   2.788,
                      6.724,   9.836,
                      2.925,   4.136,
                      5.451,   10.836,
                      2.345,   1.486,
                      4.219,   7.618)


# Extract some vectors
c <- df$logFC
d <- df$log_pval

# Your model
model <-  nls(d ~ a*exp(b*c), start = list(a = 2,b = 0.1))

# Create second dataset for new plotting
df2 <- tibble(logFC = c, log_pval =predict(model))

# Plot output
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = logFC, y = log_pval)) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x =logFC, y =log_pval)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: <code>ggplot</code> output]

### 2) `base` method

If you want to stick to `base` try ordering the `x` variables in the data frame before plotting the lines:

```r
plot(df$logFC, df$log_pval, 
     xlab = "logFC", ylab = "p_val")

df3 <- tibble(x = df$logFC, y = predict(model)) %>% dplyr::arrange(x)
lines(df3$x, df3$y, col = "dodgerblue", lty = 1, lwd = 1)
```

[image: baseplot]

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with `ggplot`. More customization can be added to the plot if needed.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + aes(x = logFC, y = log_pval) + geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(x = c, y = predict(model)))
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(logFC = c(4.315, 6.724, 2.925, 5.451, 2.345, 4.219
), log_pval = c(2.788, 9.836, 4.136, 10.836, 1.486, 7.618)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

c <- df$logFC
d <- df$log_pval
model = nls(d ~ a*exp(b*c), start = list(a = 2,b = 0.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Klink and Ronak,

It turns out the issue was the data not being ordered by size, and so 'points' plotted the unordered x-axis by the predicted y-axis, resulting in a zigzag between the predicted data.

Because ggplot presumably reorders the data before plotting, this issue has been resolved.